# How would I find a closed form expression of this sum?

Tags: summation

Earlier I was looking to find a closed form expression of the sum: 
$$\sum_{h=1}^{k-1}\left({2^{h}}{3^{k-h-1}}\right)$$
Wolfram Alpha tells me that this is equivalent to:
$$2\times{3^{k-1}}-2^k$$
However it does not explain the method of how it got there, and I cannot seem to find any resources online explaining how expressions can be found for more general cases (although I'm sure they're out there). I was wondering if anyone could give a method for deriving this or point to resources that explain how different sums can be expressed in closed form.

Thanks :)

Comment: It's part of an expression I found for the $n$th iteration of $\frac{3n+1}{2}$, so now I know that it's $({\frac{3}{2}})^k\left(n+1\right)-1$, hence the number of iterations of the Collatz function for odd $n$ to become even is one less than the power of two in the prime factorization of $n+1$

Comment: I doubt it, I just wanted to investigate the problem a bit after I saw it on numberphile

Comment: But the formula works, I've tested it. It must have already be found, surely...

Comment: I also found that all numbers of the form ${(\frac{2}{3})}^{a}\cdot(2^{3^{a-1}\cdot{(2b-1)}}+1)-1$ where a and b are positive integers definitely becomes a power of 2 after a iterations, if it's of any use.

Comment: Just did, I suck at MathJax..

Comment: I'm trying, but I don't really know how to approach it. I know that all odd numbers (written as $2^a\cdot(2b-1)-1$) will cycle to ${3^a}\cdot(2b-1)-1$, at which point they become even. But I have only really investigated the odd case so far, so that's where I'm at. Any ideas?

Comment: Other than dividing by the GCD of 3n+1 and $2^{3n+1}$, which I will look into

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at it tommorow. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^h3^{k-h-1} = 3^{k-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^h$$

Then use sum of GP.